# Python: Extract gz files with and honor original filenames and file extensions

Tags: python, gzip, filenames, unzip, gunzip

Under a folder, I have many .gz files and within these gz files some are .txt, some are .csv, some are .xml, or some other extensions.

E.g. gz (the original/compressed file in()) files in the folder will be

```
C:\Xiang\filename1.txt.gz (filename1.txt)
C:\Xiang\filename2.txt.gz (filename2.txt)
C:\Xiang\some_prefix_filename3.txt.gz (filename3.txt)
...
C:\Xiang\xmlfile1.xml_some_postfix.gz   (xmlfile1.xml)
C:\Xiang\yyyymmddxmlfile2.xml.gz       (xmlfile2.xml)
...
C:\Xiang\someotherName.csv.gz            (someotherName.csv)
C:\Xiang\possiblePrefixsomeotherfile1.someotherExtension.gz (someotherfile1.someotherExtension)
C:\Xiang\someotherfile2.someotherExtensionPossiblePostfix.gz (someotherfile2.someotherExtension)
...
```

How could I simply up-zip all the .gz files in Python on Windows 10 under the folder `C:\Xiang` and save into folder `C:\UnZipGz`, honor the original filenames, with the result as follows:

```
C:\UnZipGz\filename1.txt
C:\UnZipGz\filename2.txt
C:\UnZipGz\filename3.txt
...
C:\UnZipGz\xmlfile1.xml.
C:\UnZipGz\xmlfile2.xml.
...
C:\UnZipGz\someotherName.csv.
C:\UnZipGz\someotherfile1.someotherExtension
C:\UnZipGz\someotherfile2.someotherExtension
...
```

Generally, the gz files naming convention are consistent with the filenames of the files inside, but it is not always the case. Somehow, renaming to the some .gz files happened in the past. Now the gz file names does not necessarily match with the filenames of the file in gz files.

How could I extract all the gz files and keep the original file filenames and extensions. I.e, regardless how the gz files are named, when extracting gz files, only save the un-zip files in the original format as

```
filename.fileExtension
```

into the `C:\UnZipGz` folder.

Comment: In linux, using the command  `gunzip -N ` can honor the original filename. Does anyone know how to do it on Windows cmd, or in Python code? See post: https://superuser.com/questions/859785/is-gzip-supposed-to-honor-original-filename-during-decompress

Comment: Use https://github.com/PierreSelim/gzinfo, see my updated answer

Comment: @D Hudson, Super! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. If my answers solved your problem, please accept it. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import gzip
import os


INPUT_DIRECTORY = 'C:\Xiang'
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = 'C:\UnZipGz'
GZIP_EXTENSION = '.gz'


def make_output_path(output_directory, zipped_name):
    """ Generate a path to write the unzipped file to.

    :param str output_directory: Directory to place the file in
    :param str zipped_name: Name of the zipped file
    :return str:
    """
    name_without_gzip_extension = zipped_name[:-len(GZIP_EXTENSION)]
    return os.path.join(output_directory, name_without_gzip_extension)


for file in os.scandir(INPUT_DIRECTORY):
    if not file.name.lower().endswith(GZIP_EXTENSION):
        continue

    output_path = make_output_path(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, file.name)

    print('Decompressing', file.path, 'to', output_path)

    with gzip.open(file.path, 'rb') as file:
        with open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
            output_file.write(file.read())
```

Explanation:

1. Iterate through all files in the folder with the relevant extension.
2. Generate a path to the new directory without the gzip extension.
3. Open the file and write its decompressed contents to the new path.

---

To retrieve the original file name, you can use `gzinfo`:
https://github.com/PierreSelim/gzinfo

```py
>>> import gzinfo
>>> info = gzinfo.read_gz_info('bar.txt.gz')
>>> info.fname
'foo.txt'
```

---

*References to extract original file name:*

- https://superuser.com/questions/859785/is-gzip-supposed-to-honor-original-filename-during-decompress
- [How to get the name of the original file from a .gz archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460333/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-original-file-from-a-gz-archive)

Comment: @D Hudson,  thank you for your answer, it works with my case.  But is it possible that the name of the .gz file is not consistent with the filename inside? I have updated my question.

Comment: A gzipped file is not an archive. It doesn't contain other files or filenames within it: it's just one file compressed with the gzip algorithm. To create an archive compressed with gzip, it is common to pair gzip with tar.

Comment: @D Hudson,  thank you! You mean the gz filenames will be always consistent with the underlying file filenames. If it is the case, you code solves my problem. I was a little bit worried that the underlying file filenames may deviate with the gz filenames.

Comment: It is only a convention that the compressed name is the same as the original file + '.gz'. The original file could have been called anything. However, the compressed file itself does not keep a record of the original file name.

Comment: @D Hudson, in this case. Your above solution won't be enough since I would like to have extract the gz file and save the un-zip file in to the original name. Eg. the original file is `example1.txt`, a gz file is created as `example1.txt.gz`, but then somehow renamed as `20200211_example1.txt.gz` (but inside, the file is still `example1.txt`). You code  will save it `20200211_example1.txt` in the output folder. However, what i want is `example1.txt` in the output folder.

Comment: The gzip file does not store the original file's name, so you would need to have a mapping between the compressed file name and the name that you want to use for the decompressed file. For example: `{"20200211_example1.txt.gz": "example1.txt"}` this can then be used to look up the desired name.

Comment: it will be difficult, since in the folder there are thousands small files, and some are with Prefix/Postfix and some are not. These mapping is difficult to decide because it is hard to judge which part are prefix/postfix (if any) and which part belongs to the original filename.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228575/discussion-between-yu-xiang-and-d-hudson).

Comment: @D Hudson. Since I can use 7-zip to up-zip the test.gz file and the original file with originalFileName.txt is saved under the un-zip folder ./test. This means that the original filename information is not lost. Maybe current it is not possible using Python gzip package, but it does not mean it is not possible. I will try to find whether it is possible using other programming language/package and keep you update.

Comment: @DHudson gzip can keep a record of  the original filename internally (look for references to FNAME in RFC1952). If you use gunzip to uncompress a gzip file , the "-N" option will restore the file as its original name.